# Is using 100% CPU because of Gaming Apps makes CPU slower?

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, gaming

Ok so i just bought an Nuc5CPYH,it is second handed item.
The specs are:
Celeron N3050 (2 cores,2 Thread, 1.6 Ghz - 2.16 Ghz)
Ram DDR3L 2GB (going to upgrade to 4gb)
Windows 10 home 32bit (64 is slow)
Intel HD Graphics

I usually plays roblox,it runs smooths with 2gb but as i saw the cpu consumption it is 100%, no programs running except roblox.idk if this would cause future problems,as i already broke 1 comp and 1laptop just playing roblox... It was an Core 2 Duo and a 3rd gen celeron laptop...

But for n3050,i think heat is not a problem as it is using 14nm and i have an Air conditioned room.it never got so hot in the casing only warm

Shouls i avoid playing games like roblox and move one to more classical cpu friendly games or can i keep playing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you're alone with the Roblox high CPU issue.

https://devforum.roblox.com/t/roblox-is-killing-my-cpu/26301

Running cheaper consumer CPUs at 100% all the time is asking for trouble unfortunately. Especially laptops as they have bad thermals and air flow. I've redone a bunch of thermal paste on laptop CPUs as they were poorly applied (looking at you Dell). If you run something at 100% for long enough, the thermal paste will degrade faster than normal usage.

Even though you mention heat it not a problem, NUCs can get quite hot. The casing might be warm but that doesn't indicate how hot the internals are running.

Grab an app that measures heat like HWMonitor and check: https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html

If temps are high (80-90 degs), I'd be worried.

Comment: Thanks man,good to see that i am not the only one experiencing this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is using 100% CPU because of Gaming Apps makes CPU slower?

The answer to this question is yes and no depending on how you look at it. If your CPU is in use for the full 100%, a 2nd process will obviously have no CPU time left to do anything. As a result, CPU time is reduced for the game in order to get some CPU time for the second app. As a result, you are now utilising say... 105% where a max of 100% is possible, so the system will be 5% slower as it has to slow things down in order to reach the full potential.

However, if you mean: will lots of 100% usage make the CPU slower in the long run, as in: will it wear down the CPU?

The answer to that question is no. A CPU has no degradable parts, so it cannot slow down. It is possible that extensive 100% usage can cause for the CPU's lifespan to be reduced, given that it is electronics, but a CPU is one of the few components that is designed with stress in mind. A CPU will often run at 100% capacity for extended periods of time, and that is fine, especially if you keep in mind normal gaming use. You can expect a CPU to last for a few years easily if you use it as a gamer does, keeping in mind that the thermal condition is sufficient and no overclocking was done.

There are gamers who push their processor to the limit, overclocking them and running them at 100% most of the time. Even these users still get a few years of life out of their CPU's.

That said, part of gaming is the GPU. If a dedicated graphicscard is present, it will alleviate some (not all) of the stress of the CPU that is meant for graphics. Suffice to say, if no GPU is present, then the CPU does not only have to compute things like AI, but the graphics too, which makes the chances of running on 100% a lot more real.

Furthermore, a game is designed to run as best as possible in most of the cases, so it is very likely for any game to max out in one way or another. Some games are not programmed for multi-core use, so they may seem to not run at 100% cpu, but they still max out one of the cores. Say, you have a 4 threaded CPU, you may see that you have 26% CPU usage. 25% of the CPU is 1 thread maxed out, and 1% of usage for other stuff that runs in the background, for example, the task manager you opened to view the cpu usage.

> Shouls i avoid playing games like roblox and move one to more classical cpu friendly games or can i keep playing it?

So, to answer your final question, and to summarize this answer, Although it is a matter of opinion whether you should or not, I can safely say that it will not harm your pc if you continue to play roblox in such matter that your pc will die in a week or month from now. You may reduce the lifespan of your CPU, but if you don't want that, then why did you buy a computer?

Ask yourself this, can I upgrade/replace my computer in a year or two? As in, do you have the financial means then? If the answer is yes, then you are fine and could continue to play Roblox. If not, then consider how much you need your PC for other things.

Comment: Thanks for sharing,this is very helpful 

Comment: Thanks. Keep in mind, if you feel this answered your question, you can press the checkmark on the left to mark this answer as solved. This will let others know you no longer are seeking for help.